# How to enable text selection modal(copy/paste/select) in flutter webview?

Tags: flutter, webview

Can anyone please share the code snippet to enable the text selection model in the webview of the flutter? Till now I get that by default webview only has one gesture recognizer i.e. vertical scrolling. If anyone have code for `LongPressGestureRecognizer` please share it here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried selectable text widget?

Comment: @salma I am talking about the WebView here. How one can copy the page content in WebView just like we normally do in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `gestureRecognizers` property in WebView widget, and then you will be able to long press on WebView content
example:

```dart
   

 WebViewPlus(
    gestureRecognizers: {}..add(Factory<LongPressGestureRecognizer>(() => LongPressGestureRecognizer())),
    ...
    )
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by changing the webview package. Currently I am using [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) package and it's working fine. 
The thing was the previous webview package didn't support the touch and hold gestures.
Also, native webview for Android and iOS could also be used but no overlay can be shown in that case.

The above package works fine on both cases.

Comment: Can you give a more specific solution with code ?