# How to tap to copy html text in flutter app

Tags: flutter, developer-tools, dart-html, htmltext, html-post

My developer is building an educational app for me and we kind of have a problem. I want to know how to tap a word or phrase on the screen to show copy, highlight, web search like the image below. The app was built with flutter and the code is in dart. This feature is really needed. Will appreciate if someone can help with a plugin or just a way to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using webview package you have a gestureRecognizers property in webview widget, just add this line:

```
WebViewPlus(
  gestureRecognizers: {}..add(Factory<LongPressGestureRecognizer>(() => 
     LongPressGestureRecognizer())),...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has [selectable text](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText-class.html) for that

If he is using webview, maybe this could help?
[How to enable text selection modal(copy/paste/select) in flutter webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226651/how-to-enable-text-selection-modalcopy-paste-select-in-flutter-webview)

Comment: My developer says it doesnt work because he created the page with html texts

Comment: How is he displaying it? Via webview? And why are you asking instead of him?

Answer (score 0):

They is a package for copy and paste text in the flutter.

`FlutterClipboard.copy(item.code).then((value) {})`

[package link](https://pub.dev/packages/clipboard)

Comment: My developer says it doesnt work because he created the page with html texts

Comment: There is no way so far from webview, he should save text using flutter_html package.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got your problem.

There is a possible solution. Here you are doing is sending data from `server` in `html` format and displayed it using `html_viwer`. But there is no functionality I found to select and copy so far.

The possible solution is send `string` data from server and use `SelectableText()` to show the text and you will be able to select and copy your text.

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution for this, just use SelectableHtml widget instead of only Html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).